# What are these Auxiliary-like verbs?

Tags: grammar, verbs

"Tell", "continue" and "stop" are not listed as [auxiliary verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb#List_of_auxiliaries_in_English), but they seem to be similar. Consider the following sentences, where [these are objects of tell]:

> He **told** [his cat] to **leave**.
>
> We **told** [them] to **find** another way.
>
> [They] have been **told** to **stop calling**.

I cannot reconcile "told" as simply a transitive verb in these cases.

Consider these phrases where *tell* is used as a verb taking a single accusative object:

> He **told** [his cat].
>
> We **told** [them].
>
> [They] have been **told**.

I don't think [to leave] or [to find another way] or [to stop calling] can be considered noun phrases.

Also, we can chain together these words, often by adding the word "to" (like we do with the word *ought* which is listed as an auxiliary verb). Though sometimes this isn't necessary. A few examples of increasing complexity:

> We **continue telling** [him] to **stop** calling.
>
> We **continue** to **tell** [him] to **stop** calling.
>
> We **continue pleading** [her] to **tell** [him] to **stop** calling.
>
> We **continue pleading** [them] to **beg** [her] to **tell** [him] to **stop** calling.
>
> We **continue** to **plead** [them] to **continue** to **beg** [her] to **stop** **telling** [him] to **stop** calling.

It seems that these words can take an additional *verb phrase* as if it were a kind of object:

> Continue to _____.
>
> Stop _____.
>
> Plead [object] to _____.
>
> Tell [object] to _____.
>
> Beg [object] to _____.

Can anyone explain to me what these words are grammatically, and what those 'verb phrases' are?

Comment: The entities you're calling an "accusative object" are *indirect* objects of "tell". Compare "He told them a story." "Them" is the indirect object, "story" the direct object.

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm - you're saying that "tell" is being used here with just a single dative object?

Comment: Yes. See notes 9 and 10 at http://www.whitesmoke.com/basic-clause-structure. An indirect object doesn't always follow "to"; and an indirect object can appear without a direct object, as in "I wrote to him."

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm - my previous responses were long-winded. My point is that I think you're making a moot point by insisting that "the cat" in "he told the cat" is a dative object. What grammatical basis is there to call it a dative object? The link does not provide one.

Comment: If "him" is the indirect object in "I told him the truth", how does it become the direct object in "I told him"? The first sentence makes it clear that the direct object of "tell" is the thing(s) being communicated.

Comment: *Clear* is a matter of perspective. To me, it is **clear** that it is an accusative object because there is no use of *to*. I think this is more sensible than your reason for believing the contrary. In English, if you allow the existence of a dative object without having to use *to* or *for*, then that object's case (accusative or dative) becomes grammatically indistinguishable. If you are positing that my description of "accusative" is incorrect in this question and requires correction, then please provide reasoning more substantial than "it's clear".

Comment: You are quite right that the infinitivals "to leave", "to find another way" and "to stop calling" are not NPs. They are clauses functioning as catenative complements   "Tell" is a catenative verb and the infinitival clauses that follow them are its catenative complements.

Comment: Shoe gives the correct answer, below.

Comment: @Myridium There is no need for an indirect object to use any preposition. The term ‘dative object’ does not apply to English any more than ‘accusative object’ because English has neither of these cases. There are simply direct and indirect objects. One way to test the difference is through passivisation: a DO can be passivised as subject whether there’s an indirect object or not; an indirect object only if there is also a DO. Thus: “He told (her) a story” → “She was told a story by him/A story was told by him”; but “He told her” → “*She was told by him” does not work. _Her_ = IO, _story_ = DO.

Comment: And yes, the objects’ cases **are** indistinguishable, always, because they have the same case: object case. Prepositions don’t change that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - thanks for this explanation. I thought "She was told by him." does make sense though... but ok.

Comment: @Myridium It may possibly work in the sense of “that’s _her_ told!” (meaning ‘that’ll teach her!’)—though even there it sounds quite strange. It definitely does not work in the sense of someone else having informed her of something.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - interesting because I'm sure I sometimes say "X was told by Y" and it sounds natural to me. But there are lots of things natives say that are technically ungrammatical.

Comment: Well, I gave you a reference that specifically explains circumstances in which the indirect object *isn't preceded by "to"*. You appear to be assuming that "indirect object" is *defined* as "noun phrase preceded by 'to'". If you're going to insist on that, then obviously you're going to cast aside any illustrations that don't fit that definition. But your definition is incorrect. You're welcome to locate a reliable source that agrees with your definition.

Comment: But, "Give David the book" is pretty much exemplary of a sentence with both direct and indirect objects, and you can see that the word "to" appears nowhere in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbs such as *continue, stop, beg, tell* that can combine with other verbs are called *catenative verbs*. *The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p59) has this entry on catenative verbs:

> A verb that can form a chain with one or more subsequent verbs, e.g.
>
> - want to go
> - hate to tell you
> - begin walking
> - go shopping.
>
> The construction may involve a direct object, e.g.
>
> - She wanted *them* to go
> - He made *us* laugh
> - I watched *him* paint/painting the door.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (p1177) points out the recursive nature of catenative verbs:

> The term 'catenative' applies to a large class of constructions where
>   a verb has a non-finite internal complement. The name reflects the
>   fact that the construction can be repeated recursively, yielding a
>   concatenation ('chain') of verbs.
>
> i. I *wanted* to *arrange* for Kim to do it.
>
> ii. She *intends* to *try* to *persuade* him to *help* her redecorate her flat.

Later in the CGEL (p1206-1220) there is a lengthy section that proposes the re-analysis of auxiliaries as catenatives:

> ... the position taken here is that there are nevertheless compelling
>   grounds for preferring an analysis of the modal, tense, aspectual and
>   voice auxiliaries as catenative verbs taking non-finite
>   complementation.

The CGEL approach is called the "*catenative-auxiliary analysis*" in contrast to the traditional "*dependent-auxiliary analysis*.

Comment: Yes: nice answer. I'd just add that the intervening NPs "his cat" and "them" are 'raised' objects.

Comment: @BillJ - I had a quick look at 'raising' on Wikipedia but it's beyond me. Nevertheless thank you for this insight.

Comment: @Myridium It's really not too difficult. Syntactically, "his cat" is the direct object of "told", but it's only the _understood_ subject of  "to leave". "His cat" is called a raised object because the verb it relates to syntactically is higher in the constituent structure than the one it relates to semantically.

Comment: @BillJ - Okay, I understand. Sort of. Thank you. [The top two diagrams here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Raising_trees_1.jpg) seem to be an example of what we're talking about. Here the group of words [to happen], comparable to blank spaces ____ in my question, are labelled with the symbol "toP". Knowing that "toP" means would answer my question on what these "verb phrases" are called.

Comment: @Myridium “toP” here just means “_to_-phrase” (like a noun phrase, just a phrase distinguished by being an infinitive marked with _to_).

Comment: @Myridium They label it "toP" meaning "_to_-phrase". But it's actually a non-finite _to_-infinitival clause, not a phrase, functioning as catenative complement of the matrix verbs "expect" and "prove".