# What grammar is involved in a sentence such as "Would you like to climb a tree?"

Tags: verbs

When you say "Would you like to marry me", what part of speech is the "like" – is it a 'separate' verb? What is the grammar involved?

Comment: It is a "catenative verb". See the following link:

Comment: [What are these Auxiliary-like verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440396/what-are-these-auxiliary-like-verbs) (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a verb. Like many verbs having to do with mind and emotion (*think, believe, want, wonder, know, enjoy,* etc.), *like* takes a direct object of a complement clause that explains the particular mental or emotional state the verb indicates.

Syntactically, English has four types of complement clause. Which kind of clause gets used is determined by the verb. *Like* can take either an infinitive or a gerund complement.

- *I liked/wanted/needed/tried **to read comic books**.* (infinitive complement clause)
- *I liked/enjoyed/hated/tried **reading comic books**.* (gerund complement clause)
- *I think/believe/know/doubt/see **that he did it.*** (tensed *that*-clause complement)
- *I know/wonder/heard **why he mentioned it**.* (tensed *Wh*-clause complement)

But *like* is marginal at best with tensed complements:

- ??*I like that he did it.*
- ?**I like why he mentioned it.*

tl;dr - there are lots more like *like*; most sentences are complex, and object complements are common.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a verb. See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like

> like verb
>   \ ˈlīk  \
>   liked; liking
>   Definition of like (Entry 1 of 9)
>   transitive verb
>
> 1a : to feel attraction toward or take pleasure in : ENJOY
>   likes baseball
>   b : to feel toward : REGARD
>   how would you like a change
>   2 : to wish to have : WANT
>   would like a drink